# Leer archivo XML

Tags: java, jaxb

Tengo el siguiente programa:

```
package exercici3;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
/**
 *
 * @author Montse
 */
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder ={"autor", "nom", "editorial","isbn", "llibre"})    
public class Llibreria extends MarshalClass{

    private String autor;
    private String nom;
    private String editorial;
    private String isbn;
    private ArrayList<Llibre> llibre=new ArrayList<Llibre>();

    @XmlElement
    public String getAutor(){return autor;}
    public void setAutor (String autor){this.autor =autor;}  
    @XmlElement
    public String getNom(){return nom;}
    public void setNom (String nom){this.nom =nom;}
    @XmlElement
    public String getEditorial(){return editorial;}
    public void setEditorial (String editorial){this.editorial =editorial;}
    @XmlElement
    public String getIsbn(){return isbn;}
    public void setIsbn (String isbn){this.isbn =isbn;} 
    @XmlElement
    public ArrayList <Llibre> getLlibre() { return llibre;}
    public void setLlibre(ArrayList<Llibre> llibre){ this.llibre= llibre;}

}    






package exercici3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Montse
 */
@XmlRootElement(name="llibr")

class Llibre extends MarshalClass {

    private String autor;
    private String nom;
    private String editorial;
    private String isbn;
        private ArrayList<Llibre> llibre=new ArrayList<Llibre>();

    @XmlElement
    public String getAutor(){ return autor;}
    public void setAutor (String autor){ this.autor = autor;}

    @XmlElement
    public String getNom(){ return nom;}
    public void setNom (String nom){ this.nom = nom;}

    @XmlElement
    public String getEditorial(){ return editorial;}
    public void setEditorial (String editorial){ this.editorial = editorial;}

    @XmlElement
    public String getIsbn(){ return isbn;}
    public void setIsbn (String isbn){ this.isbn = isbn;}


     @XmlElement
    public ArrayList <Llibre> getLlibre() { return llibre;}
    public void setLlibre(ArrayList<Llibre> llibre){ this.llibre= llibre;}
    }




package exercici3;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

/**
 *
 * @author Montse
 */
public class MarshalClass {

    public void generateXML (String nameFile) {

        try{
            File file = new File (nameFile);
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(this.getClass());
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jc.createMarshaller();

            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT , true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(this, new FileWriter(nameFile, true));

        }catch (JAXBException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}



package exercici3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Montse
 */
public class Entrada {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        EscriureLlibreria();

    }

    private static void EscriureLlibreria() {

        Llibreria cc = new Llibreria();
        cc.setAutor("Xavier");
        cc.setNom("Nosotros dos");
        cc.setEditorial("Columna");
        cc.setIsbn("9788-4664-222-84");

        ArrayList<Llibre> alCU = new ArrayList<>();
      int init = 2000;
              for (int i =1; i<1;i++){
        Llibre cu = new Llibre();
        cu.setAutor(""+i);
        cu.setNom(""+i);
        cu.setEditorial(""+i);
        cu.setIsbn(""+i);
        alCU.add(cu);       
    }
                cc.setLlibre(alCU);
                cc.generateXML("llibres.xml");


    }

}
```

Quiero que el archivo que he creado llibres.xml me lo muestre por pantalla... y he hecho lo siguiente:

```
package exercici3;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
/**
 *
 * @author Montse
 */
public class Sortida {
    public static void main (String[] args) {


        try{
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Llibreria.class);
            Unmarshaller ums = context.createUnmarshaller();
            Llibre llibreria = (Llibre) ums.unmarshal(new File("llibres.xml"));
            for (Llibre llib: llibreria.getLlibre()){
                System.out.println("Nom" +llib.getNom());
                System.out.println("Autor:"+llib.getAutor());
                System.out.println("ISBN:"+llib.getIsbn());
                System.out.println("Editorial"+llib.getEditorial());
            }
        }catch (JAXBException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

me da este error :

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Montse/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Exercici3/llibres.xml; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 6; El destino de la instrucción de procesamiento que coincide con "[xX][mM][lL]" no está permitido.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:563)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
    at exercici3.Sortida.main(Sortida.java:18)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Montse/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Exercici3/llibres.xml; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 6; El destino de la instrucción de procesamiento que coincide con "[xX][mM][lL]" no está permitido.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPIData(XMLScanner.java:746)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanPIData(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1014)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPI(XMLScanner.java:714)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1413)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
    ... 6 more
```

Que tengo mal??

gracias!!

EDITO

El error sale por que el archivo lo crea varias veces. Como puedo modificarlo para que lo cree solo una vez?

Luego ahora el error que me da:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: exercici3.Llibreria cannot be cast to exercici3.Llibre
    at exercici3.Sortida.main(Sortida.java:18)
C:\Users\Montse\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Debería poner `llibres.xml`,es posible que no este bien conformado y no sea un xml válido

Comment: Habiendo respondido a una anterior pregunta sobre este asunto, me he dado cuenta que el código que crea el archivo `llibres.xml`, si lo ejecutas dos veces, no sobre-escribe el archivo, sino que agrega otra vez el mismo contenido, encabezado incluido, al archivo ya existente. Entonces, tendrás un xml no válido. Primero prueba eso: borra `llibres.xml`, corre el código de creación del archivo **una sola vez** y verifica si no da este error. Si el error persiste valida el XML con alguna herramienta en línea para verificar que no se está creando con errores.

Comment: @A.Cedano tienes razón me da otro error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: exercici3.Llibreria cannot be cast to exercici3.Llibre
 at exercici3.Sortida.main(Sortida.java:18)
C:\Users\Montse\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds) 


Como puedo arreglar que lo cree solo una vez?

Comment: También hay otro problema en el código, pues al principio de la clase **`LlibreriaEscriure`** tienes esto : `Llibreria cc = new Llibreria();
        cc.setAutor("Xavier");
        cc.setNom("Nosotros dos");
        cc.setEditorial("Columna");
        cc.setIsbn(978-84-664-2228-4);` lo cual crea un XML irregular, parecido a esto: `<llibreria>
    <autor>Xavier</autor>
    <nom>Nosotros dos</nom>
    <editorial>Columna</editorial>
    <isbn>-2002</isbn>
    <llibre>
        <autor>1</autor>
        <editorial>1</editorial>
        <isbn>1</isbn>
        <nom>1</nom>
    </llibre>`

Comment: Quizá esto último no sea un problema, pero podría serlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano no lo sé estoy bastante perdida..

Comment: No deberías poner el XMLElement a los atributos? porque veo que los pones a los métodos

Comment: Para que te cree un archivo XML cada vez, tienes que modificar la parte donde creas el archivo en la clase `MarshalClass`, agregando `false`en la línea donde creas el archivo. O sea: **`jaxbMarshaller.marshal(this, new FileWriter(nameFile, false));`**  Por lo demás, debe haber una forma para otorgar al XML de todos sus encabezados respectivos para que no haya problemas en su lectura. No tengo mucha experiencia con XML por eso no puedo hablarte con propiedad, es cuestión de investigar. Aunque el validator en línea dice que el XML es correcto. Borra el archivo, corrige lo que te dije y prueba.

Comment: El error que nombras aquí: "Luego ahora el error que me da:" es porque intentas castear un objeto Llibreria a uno Llibre y no se puede.

Comment: Puedes compartir el archivo llibres.xml por favor??

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano tiene razon, la linea `Llibre llibreria = (Llibre) ums.unmarshal(new File("llibres.xml"));` debe ser `Llibreria llibreria = (Llibreria) ums.unmarshal(new File("llibres.xml"));`

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano gracias por tu ayuda! Ahora ya me funciona :) Gracias por todo lo que me habéis aportado

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias!! Ahora ya lo tengo! Mil gracias por los comentarios!

Comment: Yo te recomiendo que revises la librería `XStream` que convierte de objetos java a XML y viceversa, y ademas me parece mas flexible y potente que las apis nativas de java. Al principio cuesta un poco de trabajo entenderla pero con este tutorial es mas sencillo: http://x-stream.github.io/alias-tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

al final creo que puedes usar esta forma

```
public class Sortida {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Llibreria.class);
        Unmarshaller ums = context.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<Llibre> rootElementCast = ums.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new File("llibres.xml")), Llibre.class);
        Llibre llibreria = rootElementCast.getValue();
        //for (Llibre llib : llibreria.getLlibre()) {
            System.out.println("Nom" + llibreria.getNom());
            System.out.println("Autor:" + llibreria.getAutor());
            System.out.println("ISBN:" + llibreria.getIsbn());
            System.out.println("Editorial" + llibreria.getEditorial());
            //des-n
            System.out.println("libre" + llibreria.getLlibre());
        //}
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

segun la documentacion [aqui](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#unmarshalling-xmlrootelement-and-unmarshalling)

lo estuve probando por mi mismo y aunque *Libre* tiene la anotacion `XmlRootElement` en la documentación especifican otra forma de hacerlo y esta me funciono.

Comment: ahora si gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

He estado buscando y el error ([en la versión en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889132/error-the-processing-instruction-target-matching-xxmmll-is-not-allowed))

> The processing instruction target matching “[xX][mM][lL]” is not
>   allowed

Significa que el inicio del fichero no es **exactamente** `<?xml ...>`.
Esos caracteres sólo pueden estar en la primera línea del fichero y seguramente no se admite que tengan ni un espacio delante (depende de la rigurosidad del analizador sintáctico (parser) usado